# Taylorseries of $\cos(x)e^x$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion

Lets consider $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R, f(x)=\cos(x)e^x$.

I want to calculate the taylor-series around $x_0=0$ and I want to check if the taylor-series is equal to $f(x)$.

The first derivatives are:

$f'(x)=-e^x(\sin(x)-\cos(x))$

$f''(x)=-2e^x\sin(x)$

$f'''(x)=-2e^x(\sin(x)+\cos(x))$

$f^{(4)}(x)=-4e^x\cos(x)$.

From that point I can see the pattern, but I dont know how I can write this as one term..

How should I compare the resulting taylor series with $f(x)$? Should I use the series of $\cos(x)$ and $e^x$ and calculate the cauchy product of them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would put $\cos x=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$.

Comment: Did you try to use the fact that $e^x\cos(x)$ is the real part of $e^{(1+i)x}$?

Comment: What do you mean by "I dont know how i can write this as one term"?